# How to see what Redis-Commands RESP representation

Tags: c#, redis

Hello is there a way to find out the string representation of Redis commands , following the `RESP` protocol?


For example i am trying to get all the keys from the database using the `Keys *` command.
However i do not know if this command is a `simple string` or a `Bulk string` or an `Array of Bulk Strings`:

**Simple String** representation: `+Keys *\r\n`
**Bulk String** representation: `$6\r\nKeys *\r\n`
 **Array of Bulk String**  representation : `*1\r\n$6\r\nKeys *\r\n`

Is there any way to see the `bytes`/`string` that the Redis-server knows how to respond to?
Is there any lookup table ?

For `Keys` command according to the `REDIS` documentation it is not stated how the request message should be constructed :

> Returns all keys matching pattern.
>
> > While the time complexity for this operation is O(N), the constant
> >     times are fairly low. For example, Redis running on an entry level
> >     laptop can scan a 1 million key database in 40 milliseconds.

```
Examples
redis> MSET firstname Jack lastname Stuntman age 35
"OK"
redis> KEYS *name*
1) "lastname"
2) "firstname"
redis> KEYS a??
1) "age"
redis> KEYS *
1) "lastname"
2) "firstname"
3) "age"
redis>
```

Comment: why don't you use one of the Redis clients? https://redis.io/clients

Comment: Long story short i can not use the existing API (StackExchangeRedis or other) because internal policy.Is there no way to find out what the redis-server "spits-out" as response? Was thinking of WireShark or some other software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use telnet to connect to the redis server and type your command. You will see the output without any post processing.

Comment: Thank you very much , i tried it and it is exactly what i needed.